# Can I access the render screen size in a custom filter 2D in the game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, shaders, opengl

I am using Blender Game Engines Filter 2D to make a post effect with GLSL.
In an fragment shader applied on the frame buffer, I want to access the size in pixels of that buffer in GLSL.

```
uniform vec2 screensize;
```

This is possible for objects of the type [BL_Shader](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bge.types.BL_Shader.html)

```
shader.setUniform2f("screensize", w, h)
```

The viewport size can be accessed in this way

```
import bge

w = bge.render.getWindowWidth()
h = bge.render.getWindowHeight()

print (w,h)
```

But I don't know how to get the BL_Shader object. The [SCA_2DFilterActuator](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bge.types.SCA_2DFilterActuator.html) does not have any reference to such object.

```
co = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
distortion = co.actuators["riftDistortion"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the game properties stored in the object that calls the Filter 2D are passed to the shader as uniforms. So if you have a width and a height float game properties you can set their values at run-time to match the window size.

However, be aware that the window size (which you get from `render.getWindowWidth()` or `render.getWindowHeight()`) is not the buffer size. The buffersize is the closest power of two for that dimension (e.g., a window that is `1024 x 768` will have as buffers `1024 x 1024`).

Comment: That said, I can't see why do you want to access the size of the buffer in pixels. You are much better of by using the normalized coordinates of the visible part of the buffer. You get this with `gl_TexCoord[3]` [link](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?139829-New-Texcoord-3-canvas-coordinate-options-in-2DFilters)

Comment: Thank you, gl_TextCoord[3] helped. I am also able to set Uniforms with Python. I didn't know that the buffer size differs to the screen size, interesting. I am trying to achieve a optical distortion inversion for the Oculus Rift, the screen size is needed to achieve that. I actually have another question related to that.